# Are <?> and <E> interchangeable?

Tags: java, generics

[Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) says that `<?>` and `<T>` are interchangeable. Why then can I compile line [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) below, while I cannot compile line [2]?

```
abstract class A<K extends Number>{
  abstract public A<?> f(A<?> k); //[1]
  abstract public <S> A<S> f(A<S> k); //[2]
}
```

Comment: because <?> in your case is the same as without generic type at all(try to remove `<``>` and it will also compile), but if you specify type parameter, it has to point to type that is child of Number, because you declare this.

Comment: But if I'll remove all <S>'s it will also compile, but that doesn't mean anything!)

Comment: I want to know why aren't `< ? >` influenced by `<K extends Number>`? this is main question) <?>, like <S>, means __any type__ here, doesn't it?

Comment: actually not. Suppose your class as container(perheps `List` would be  better example). If you have a reference `List<?>` it means that it can hold object of any class of `List` hierarchy and with any type parameter, but you can only iterate through objects in such collection(or get specified one), in all cases it will return `Object` as collection element. You can not insert anything in such list, because you can not guarantee type safety.

Comment: why aren't __<?>'s__ influenced by <K extends Number> while __<S>'s__ are?

Comment: beacause compiler treats differently to `<?>` and to `<S>`

Comment: That's logical thing, compiler didn't want to compile [2]. But why does occur the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of reading and searching, I have eventually found the answer to my own question.
First of all, I have to say about `<?>`, there is some information here.

> So what is the supertype of all kinds of collections? It's  written
>   Collection`<?>` (pronounced "collection of  unknown"), that is, a
>   collection whose element type  matches anything.([Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html))

Ok, so our `A<?>` is super type of **all** kinds of As.
And parametr `A<?>` can accept any of As (polymorphically) as a argument therefore line [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) compiles.
[image: Java tutorials]

Java specification tells us:

> Wildcards are a restricted form of existential types. Given a generic
>   type declaration `G<T extends B>`, `G<?>` is roughly analogous 
>   to Some `X<:B`. `G<X>`

**B** stands for bounds; `X<:B` indicates that the subtype relation holds between
types X and B.

Therefore `A<?>` is indeed *auto-restricted*;

When we declare type argument `<S>`, it is, in some way, as if we declared `class S{}`, type **S** don't have any relations to Number(our bound) and cast to one would fail, so we should declare that "S extends Number" to have the same effect as for `<?>`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to restrict `S` to extend `Number`:

```
abstract class A<K extends Number>{
    //abstract public A<?> f(A<?> k); //[1] 
    abstract public <S extends Number> A<S> f(A<S> k); //[2]
}
```

I guess when you use `<?>` it's auto-restricted - really don't know.

Comment: I though the same thing, but i cannot be certain(

Answer (score 0):

`?` and `T` are interchangeable (not truly, as you are loosing the exact type) given there are no bounds. 
In this case, `K` has a bound that it extends `Number`

Hence making it to `abstract public <S extends Number> A<S> f(A<S> k);` will do

Answer (score 0):

this compiles fine for me:

```
abstract class A<K extends Number>
{
//  abstract public A<?> f(A<?> k); //[1] 
    abstract public A<K> f(A<K> k); 
}
```

Comment: I changed something, but I should have not done it) I mean S not K)